# Numpy, compiling from scratch, give wrong results

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-3.4

Hi I just downloaded and installed numpy, for python3, in my machine.

So, I downloaded the 1.9.1 version from the numpy website, and I run `python3 setupt.py install`

After this, I tried this code:

```
myuser@myhost:~/myfolder> python3
Python 3.4.1 (default, Oct 27 2014, 15:58:36) 
[GCC 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.9.1'
>>> A=np.array([0.,0.6,0.,0.,0.,0.])
>>> A
array([  0.00000000e+00,   6.00000000e-01,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00])
>>> print(A>0.001)
[False False  True False False False]
>>> A
array([  0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.])
```

As a result of `A>0.001`, I expect an array like  `[False True False False False False]`, so numpy result is wrong. And after that, `A` is even changed!

Since this kind of error seems very trivial, I suppose there is something wrong in the compile process (and not a problem of numpy).

So, is this some common problem in compiling numpy? are there some flag one can try to add in compile time, to solve that kind of problem?